# PHP: SeekableIterator::seek()

Tags: php, seek, seekableiterator

If I want to implement seek() to complete the SeekableIterator interface, should I internally revert to the old position if the seeked position is invalid? Like this:

```
public function seek( $position )
{
    $oldPosition = $this->_position;
    $this->_position = $position;
    if( !$this->valid() )
    {
        $this->_position = $oldPosition;
        throw new OutOfBoundsException( 'Invalid seek position (' . $position . ')' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the php.net [interface reference's example implementation](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSeekableIterator.html#f3394acf5396d09737804074b3ab5e19) as a guideline, then no, you should not "revert" to the original position, even if the supplied target position isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [sample code from the SPL documentation](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSeekableIterator.html#f3394acf5396d09737804074b3ab5e19), you should still change the position.

Comment: I see we had the same idea. ;)